# Reference a managedBean inside Controller bean

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

i want to pass reference of my Managedbean inside Controller bean as an argument. my Domain Entity is Brand. and i want to set properties of brand from JSF page component. and i want to pass that managedBean reference in controller method and this controller addBrand method getBrandService and save the respective brand Bean. please guide me. thanks :)
this is my managed bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BrandBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String brandName;
    private String brandDecription;
//getters and setters
}
```

and this is my Controller bean for Brand:
    // addBrand Method takes brand instance as a parameter. brand is Model Object.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BrandController extends AbstractController{
    private IBrandService brandService;

    public IBrandService getBrandService() {
        brandService = new BrandService();
        return brandService;
    }

    public void setBrandService(IBrandService brandService) {
        this.brandService = brandService;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
    public void addBrand(String brandName, String brandDecription){
        try{
            Brand brand = new Brand();
            brand.setBrandName(brandName);
            brand.setBrandDecription(brandDecription);
            getBrandService().addBrand(brand);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `AbstractController` is not part of JSF and therefore not recognized by JSF `@ManagedBean`. You're mixing/confusing JSF with Spring MVC.

Comment: @BalusC please provide me useful link.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Spring. I suggest to get straight what exactly you want. You're basically trying to mix 2 completely different MVC frameworks which just doesn't make sense.

Comment: i should remove BrandController from my project. and handle my trasaction straight with ManagedBean Which is BrandBean. right?

Comment: As BalusC tells, stay with one of the two *view frameworks*: JSF, or Spring MVC. The former is the *component-based framework* and the latter is *request-based framework* for developing web applications. Next, you could use Spring (not Spring MVC) for the *middle tier* (read: for DB access and transactions) instead of EJBs so that your application can run on servlet containers like Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BrandBean implements Serializable {
    private int brandId;
    private String brandName;
    private String brandDescription;
    private List<Brand> brands;
    private List<Brand> filter;


    public List<Brand> getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    public void setFilter(List<Brand> filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    public List<Brand> getBrands() {
        return brands;
    }
    public void setBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
        this.brands = brands;
    }
    public int getBrandId() {
        return brandId;
    }
    public void setBrandId(int brandId) {
        this.brandId = brandId;
    }
    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }
    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }
    public String getBrandDescription() {
        return brandDescription;
    }
    public void setBrandDescription(String brandDescription) {
        this.brandDescription = brandDescription;
    }

}

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BrandController {
    private BrandBean bean;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{BrandService}")
    private BrandService brandService;
public BrandController() {
        bean = new BrandBean();


    }
    }
```